# Updating an element in PySimpleGUI without user input

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I want to use PySimpleGUI to display the current time read from my computer. However, when I use the update function to update the current time, the screen does not change.

My original idea was to read events and values, and if events = None was true, then I would update the text as shown in the following code:

```
import datetime
import PySimpleGUI as sg


curr = datetime.datetime.now()
currentHour = curr.hour
currentMinute = curr.minute
x = str(currentHour) + ":" + str(currentMinute)

sg.theme('SystemDefault')
layout_title = [[sg.Text("Alarm Clock", justification = 'c', font = ("Times New Roman", 100), text_color = ('red'))]]
time = sg.Text(x, key = 'text', font = ("Times New Roman", 100))
layout_time = [[time]]
layout = [[sg.Column(layout_title, justification = 'c')], [sg.Column(layout_time, justification = 'c')]]
window = sg.Window("Alarm Clock", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    window.Maximize()
    curr = datetime.datetime.now()
    currentHour = curr.hour
    currentMinute = curr.minute
    x = str(currentHour) + ":" + str(currentMinute)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        window.close()
        break
    if event in (None):
        window['text'].update(x)
    else:
        window['text'].update(0) #added for debugging; should either update to current time or 0, but neither work
```

Looking at examples in the documentation and online, I noted they update the text after the user provided some input. For debugging, I added a button to my layout and edited the code to change text when the button was pressed. This modification is shown below:

```
import datetime
import PySimpleGUI as sg


curr = datetime.datetime.now()
currentHour = curr.hour
currentMinute = curr.minute
x = str(currentHour) + ":" + str(currentMinute)

sg.theme('SystemDefault')
layout_title = [[sg.Text("Alarm Clock", justification = 'c', font = ("Times New Roman", 100), text_color = ('red'))]]
time = sg.Text(x, key = 'text', font = ("Times New Roman", 100))
layout_time = [[time]]
layout = [[sg.Column(layout_title, justification = 'c')], [sg.Column(layout_time, justification = 'c')], [sg.Button("Enter to change Text")]] #button is added to layout
window = sg.Window("Alarm Clock", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    window.Maximize()
    curr = datetime.datetime.now()
    currentHour = curr.hour
    currentMinute = curr.minute
    x = str(currentHour) + ":" + str(currentMinute)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        window.close()
        break
    if event in ("Enter to change Text"): #instead of updating when nothing happens, update when the button is pressed
        window['text'].update(x)

    else:
        window['text'].update(0) #added for debugging; should either update to current time or 0, but neither work
```

Now when I press the button, the time will change on the screen. Is there a way to update elements without providing any input, or is this the best solution possible?

Comment: Your explanation of what you want to do is confusing.  Can you elaborate on what specifically you are trying to accomplish?  For example, you state: "My original idea was to read events and values, and if events = None was true, then I would update the text as shown in the following code"  How are you detecting events?  What specific text are you updating?  What is the meaning of "Now when I press the button, the time will change on the screen. Is there a way to update elements without providing any input, or is this the best solution possible?"?

Comment: I had a similar problem in the past and I don't think it is possible to accomplish this using only PySimpleGUI. I solved it by modifying the root Tkinter object that the PySimpleGUI used.

Comment: Many ways to get events other than user input. Timer API, use a timeout on the window.read, send event from a thread (window.write_event_value call).

Comment: @itprorh66 

Input is taken using the read method. If None is returned, the displayed time should change. In other words, the time on the screen should change automatically without the user needing to input anything.

The text that I am updating is the text element of the window with key = ‘text’. 

Concerning the button, I added that because from examples I saw, user input was taken before changing an element of the window. Therefore, I rewrote the code to change the element ‘text’ when the button was pressed. This gave the correct output, but I want it to happen automatically.

Comment: @DaviA.Sampaio I am new to making GUIs and have only used PySimpleGUI to do so, so maybe it is too early to say this, but this library seems limited in its capabilities. I might have to consider using another tool to make GUIs.

Comment: @HamzaBeder I agree. PySimpleGUI is for very simple applications. If your application is complex, I recommend making it a web app (using Flask or Django for example) and then using PyWebview to make it a Windows desktop application.

Comment: `event in (None)` is a wrong  Python statement and will get exception: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable. `event in ("Enter to change Text")` is also a bad statement.

Comment: @JasonYang Ah ok. From searching online, I see that error is because NoneType is not a Python Iterator, so instead of `event in (None)` I can try `event is (None)`, although that also did not cause the screen to update upon no input.                    
 Also, instead of `event in ("Enter to change Text")` I would do `event == ("Enter to change Text")`. I noted that when I change the code to `event in ("Enter to change Text abc")`, it still causes the screen to change because "Enter to change Text" is a substring of "Enter to change Text abc"

Answer (score 2):

If nothing wrong, it can be done by PySimpleGUI easily.

> Pass in a timeout (in milliseconds) to wait for a maximum of timeout milliseconds. Will return timeout_key if no other GUI events happen first.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import PySimpleGUI as sg

font1 = ("Courier New",  20, 'bold')
font2 = ("Courier New", 100, 'bold')
sg.theme('DarkBlue3')

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Alarm Clock", font=font1, justification='c', expand_x=True)],
    [sg.Text("", size=8, font=font2, key='Time')],
]
window = sg.Window('Alarm Clock', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        now = datetime.now()
        text = f'{now.hour:0>2d}:{now.minute:0>2d}:{now.second:0>2d}'
        window['Time'].update(text)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this accomplishes my goal. I think this method is easier than the one using threading, so for the purposes of my project I think this is sufficient. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For simple case here, above code is sufficient. For extra function take time to finish, then threading will be required.

Answer (score 0):

Jason provided the most common way to generate events that are not user generated.  Here's an example showing 3 ways non-user events can be made.  The Timer API call has been commented out.  That API has not yet been released publicly.  It can be downloaded from GitHub.  The [PySimpleGUI Demo Programs](https://demos.pysimplegui.org/) are a great place to look to learn about these techniques.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time

'''
    Generating events from read timeout, timer API, threads
'''

def a_thread(window:sg.Window):
    # Geneates an event every 4 seconds
    while True:
        time.sleep(4)
        window.write_event_value('-THREAD EVENT-', 0)

layout = [  [sg.Text('Event generation example')],
            [sg.Text('Timout counter'), sg.Text(key='-TIMEOUT COUNTER-', size=3)],
            [sg.Text('Thread counter'), sg.Text(key='-THREAD COUNTER-', size=3)],
            [sg.Text('Timer counter'), sg.Text(key='-TIMER COUNTER-', size=3)],
         ]

window = sg.Window('Events not genearted by a user', layout, finalize=True, font='_ 15', element_justification='r')

# Timer API call requires GitHub version of PySimpleGUI currently
# window.timer_start(frequency_ms=2000, key='-TIMER EVENT-', repeating=True)      # recurring timer event every 2 seconds
window.start_thread(lambda: a_thread(window))

timeout_counter = 0
timer_counter = 0
thread_counter = 0

while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=200)        # event every 200 ms
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        window['-TIMEOUT COUNTER-'].update(timeout_counter)
        timeout_counter +=1
    elif event == '-TIMER EVENT-':
        window['-TIMER COUNTER-'].update(timer_counter)
        timer_counter +=1
    if event == '-THREAD EVENT-':
        window['-THREAD COUNTER-'].update(thread_counter)
        thread_counter +=1

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this solution and Jason's both work for me. The reason the thread counter is incrementing more slowly is because you are injecting the Thread Event at a slower rate than a time out occurs. I did not know about threading and the write_event_value function, but they will definitely be helpful for later projects. Thank you for your help.